# Microsoft's ASLR is weird

Tags: windows, dll, portable-executable, aslr

I watched a ASLRed **dll** images's based address for 32bit Process.
It's not a fully randomization. It just randomizated 1/2 probability.

For example, once I load a dll then the image is loaded on **0x12345678**.
And I load the image again, the image is loaded on **0x23456789**.(Base address is changed!)
But I load the image again
**0x12345678

0x23456789

0x12345678

0x23456789**
...

Why they did implement like this?
Is it for a crash report's frequency?(For getting same crash addresses of re-deployed dlls)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is by design. Normally, Windows selects a preferred base address for an ASLR DLL when the DLL is first loaded, and then it keeps using that address until the system is rebooted. That way the DLL will be mapped at the same address in every process that loads it, allowing code pages to be shared.

However, if a DLL has been unloaded from every process, the system may sometimes select a different base address the next time the DLL is loaded. It does this to reduce virtual address space fragmentation, not for security reasons. This is what seems to be happening in your case.

Answer (score 3):

It's documented as being at [one of 1 of 256 possible starting addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/26/address-space-layout-randomization-in-windows-vista.aspx).

But i didn't think it even applied to a process, but to shared DLL's.

ASLR: [is not on by default for process images](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=100). It's an opt-in thing, for compatiblity.([3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430720.aspx))

> **Address Space Layout Randomization
>   (ASLR)**
>
> ASLR moves executable images into
>   random locations when a system boots,
>   making it harder for exploit code to
>   operate predictably. For a component
>   to support ASLR, all components that
>   it loads must also support ASLR. For
>   example, if A.exe consumes B.dll and
>   C.dll, all three must support ASLR. By
>   default, Windows Vista and later will
>   randomize system DLLs and EXEs, but
>   DLLs and EXEs created by ISVs must opt
>   in to support ASLR using the
>   /DYNAMICBASE linker option.
>
> ASLR also randomizes heap and stack
>   memory:
>
> - When an application creates a heap in
>     Windows Vista and later, the heap
>     manager will create that heap at a
>     random location to help reduce the
>     chance that an attempt to exploit a
>     heap-based buffer overrun succeeds.
>     Heap randomization is enabled by
>     default for all applications running
>     on Windows Vista and later.
> - When a
>     thread starts in a process linked with
>     /DYNAMICBASE, Windows Vista and later
>     moves the thread's stack to a random
>     location to help reduce the chance
>     that a stack-based buffer overrun
>     exploit will succeed.

Comment: Please give me a URL of the document.

Comment: Thanks lan. For a EXE PE, I think it might be right. But for a Dll, it still works 1/2 probability. It's weird. Is Michael Howard wrong? -Of course I don't believe he is wrong. There might be something I misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

Had installed new Win8 RC x64 yesterday.

Watch out!

Kernel32.dll (64-bit version) have different base address in different processes (in single session, of course). Only ntdll.dll base address remains constant. I had to change the code, you can no longer rely on the permanent address Loadlibrary.