# why do some Windows applications contain a relocation directory?

Tags: portable-executable

If my understanding of the Windows Portable Executable specification is correct, relocation tables are only needed when libraries cannot be loaded at their prefered addresses. Why do some applications (e.g. chrome.exe) contain a relocation table? Are applications not always loaded at their preferred addresses?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655185/microsofts-aslr-is-weird

Answer (score 3):

It's for [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Space_Layout_Randomization)

AFAIK, current system loader don't relocate .exe files, maybe because it will increase loading time.
However, in next versions of OS, loader will relocate EXEs. (When hardware will be fast enough)

Comment: As mentioned, as far as I understand the PE Specification, a Relocation table is ONLY needed in a DLL, NOT in an EXE (since an EXE is NEVER relocated !)..ASLR never relocates EXE.

Comment: `.exe` can be relocated too, why not

Comment: Could you add more information about ASLR to this post? Even though you linked to Wikipedia, it'll help others who check this question for an answer.

Comment: @Abyx: Could you please explain WHY exe would ever be relocated? Please provide more details and a concrete answer.

Comment: Interesting, So relocation table was brought up after the idea of ASLR ?

Comment: @warl0ck: No. Relocation tables are primarily there to know which addresses need to have a delta added to them in case the library can't be loaded at its preferred address. They are there at least since Windows NT 3.x: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx