# "virtual address" in dumpbin output of a dll

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, cpu-architecture

1)
In dumpbin output of a dll, I see below attribute "virtual address" under code section

SECTION HEADER #1

.text name

```
100C virtual size
1000 virtual address (1C001000 to 1C00200B)
1200 size of raw data
 400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 000015FF)
   0 file pointer to relocation table
   0 file pointer to line numbers
   0 number of relocations
   0 number of line numbers
```

60000020 flags

```
      Code

     Execute Read
```

[image: scn2]

[image: scn1]

2)
Screenshot Scn2.png(attached) is left hand side  part of scn1.png(attached).

My question is,
Is the above attribute virtual address range(1C001000 to 1C00200B)  nothing but offset(Effective address) in red circle as per screenshot(attached)?

Comment: Please let me know, if virtual address that dumpbin 32 bit dll output dislaying same as address mentioned in red circle in the above sreenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, technically (as for as the Portable Executable specification is concerned), the Virtual Address attribute is the offset of the Section from the ImageBase where the Image wll be loaded (this is also an point which depends on ASLR) in MEMORY.

Some tools, like dumpin, automatically compute the result and show the Virtual Address resulting from the addition to the Image Base. In this case, yes you're right, "the range is nothing but offset(Effective address)"!

Comment: and image base is decided by the os loader?

Comment: i did not get u, when u said ASLR.
CAN U HELP ME?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655185/microsofts-aslr-is-weird/3655277#3655277

Comment: So that means, "virtual address" value in dumpbin output holds good despite change in image base due to ASLR? Who decides the image base, is it the OS loader?

Comment: Dumpbin is a static anylysis tool. It does not take care of any ASLR issue, since the binary anylysed in not really mapped. ASLR is a dynamic issue which handled and resolved (when needed) by the OS, the loader.

Comment: but can i set that offset is already decided statically by linker only, as per dumpbin output? And image base will be decided at load time which is clarified.

Comment: Yes, compiler MUST do assumptions about many things. The ImageBaseAddress is one of these (otherwise the addresses of variables could not be resolved). I suggest that you google on the "Microsoft Portable Executable Format Specification" and have a look at the specification of the Windows executables.

Comment: For your statement: "compiler MUST do assumptions about many things. The ImageBaseAddress is one of these (otherwise the addresses of variables could not be resolved)."                                                 How can compiler assume what the image base address is? it depends on the runtime scenario?

Comment: Compiler are "static" and do not have something to do with any runtime issue. The ImageBaseAddress is given (explicitly or by default) during compile (link) processing.

Comment: Calculating offset for all the sections of binary make sense to me. But How can a Compiler or linker decide ImageBaseAddress of that binary? Because it is Global descriptor table that tell that this is the base address for each segment(data/code), if you see my attached diagram in my query. So, what i understand as of now is that virtual address mentioned in dumpbin output is nothing but the offset address mentioned in red circle in my attached diagram. Now i would like to understand, How segment selector(16 bit) gets its value for each segment(code/data) in that diagram?

Comment: did your read the PE Specification? and the "standard" Matt Pietrek's articles about PE, the compilers's tasks and the way the loader handles image files?

Comment: sure mox, i will read article and then try to understand the above two diagrams with the the program that gets loaded. I was scared to read pe spec, because it is 203 pages.                             Sham

Comment: I understand, but, believe, once you get trough the complete spec, you'll have a much better view of how images are built, consume by the loader and how they can be misused...!

Comment: hello mox                           in this doc, i see PE EXE file layout and COFF file layout.             And what i know is, all windows objects files and executables are COFF file formats.     So, can u tell me what is PE executable format?              Sham

Comment: @user1787812: I not sure I understand your question. This threat is getting long. Should you have questions related to PE, I'll be glad to answer these on Stackoverflow. Create new questions on this purpose!

Comment: mox,                         how do i close this  question. I also want to accept your answer.                   Sham

Comment: ok, makes sense. You can close it also by accepting it a the right answer.

Comment: Hello mox               As you said i raised query by title "query on mark pieter article on pe_coff spec" Please answer it.          Sham

Comment: I do not see any link/option to accept the answer): Please help me

Comment: On the left of the begin of my Answer, there is a "0". The Arrows (up/down). You select (click) on the upper Arrow to accept the Answer.